# Segment black AND moving Pixels

Tags: python, opencv, video, background, image-segmentation

I’m trying to segment the moving propeller of this Video. My approach is, to detect all black and moving pixels to separate the propeller from the rest.
Here is what I tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


x,y,h,w = 350,100,420,500 # Croping values


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Video Path')
  

while(1):        
    _, frame = cap.read() 
    
    frame = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w] # Crop Video
    
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
    lower_black = np.array([0,0,0]) 
    upper_black = np.array([360,255,90]) 
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_black, upper_black) 
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask) 
    
    nz = np.argwhere(mask)
                                
            
    cv2.imshow('Original',frame)
    cv2.imshow('Propeller Segmentation',mask)
  
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff # press esc to exit
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Screenshot form the Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwvjO.jpg)

[Result of the Segmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dotPb.png)

[With function cv.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXYbH.png)

Comment: **this video** appears to be the source. https://youtu.be/dNVtMmLlnoE?t=183 it is hand-held footage, i.e. camera moves relative to objects/scene. it is **useless** for any simple processing. you'd first have to **stabilize** the clip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a look at [background subtraction.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreground_detection#:%7E:text=Background%20subtraction%20is%20any%20technique,(object%20recognition%20etc.).&text=Foreground%20detection%20separates%20foreground%20from,taking%20place%20in%20the%20foreground.) It should be the right approach for your problem.

OpenCV provides a good tutorial on this: [Link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html)

Comment: I already tried this algorithm. The result is like this:


https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXYbH.png

Comment: IMHO it is premature to advise to use findContours. background subtraction should work, unless something is going on that we haven't been told/shown.... and I'm right.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I think you are right, don't how deep op went into the bgs parameters. Let's have a look at the video.

Comment: It worked. However the result was no perfect with `cv.BackgroundSubtractor.apply()`. I also used `cv.erode()` to remove all the other artefacts.